# ng-mocks giving error about imports with jest-preset-angular

Tags: jest-preset-angular, ng-mocks

Using ng-mocks 13.5.2 with jest-preset-angular 12 and @ngneat/spectator 11 I am getting the below error any time I try to use `MockComponents` or `MockPipe` in my spec file.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

> Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/scott/ltr/ltr/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs.

at Runtime.requireModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1011:21)
at node_modules/ng-mocks/webpack:/ng-mocks/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:3:36
at Object.**WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE__8900** (node_modules/ng-mocks/webpack:/ng-mocks/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10:19)

Comment: Hi Gargoyle, could you submit a bug report in the lib's github? https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks/issues/new?assignees=satanTime&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md&title=Bug%3A+

I need a min project with the failure, if it's possible to get.
Or: package.json, tsconfig.json (and all other tsconfigs if they exist), jest config, angular.json / nx.json, nodejs version.

Comment: ng-mocks is still based on CommonJS and to migrate to ESM, I need an example where it fails with CommonJS and works with ESM only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was reported and fixed, please use the latest version of `ng-mocks`: 14.0.1 or younger.

The problem was triggered by the `node`'s flag: `--experimental-vm-modules`, which forces to use `imports` instead of `require`, whereas `ng-mocks` hadn't provided an `esm` build.

The fix was implemented here:

- https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks/pull/2848
- https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks/issues/2846